# running jenkins on container and the container in the pipelines on the host machine

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to run Jenkins in the docker container but instead of running the container that Jenkins makes on the same container, I need it to run on the host machine what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: The pipelines would need to run in the Jenkins JVM _within the container_.... You could run a Jenkins slave on the host, directly, I guess, but then what's the point of Docker?

Comment: so I could host Jenkins without installing it on my host machine.
if I am letting it run a docker container inside the container Jenkins in it becomes tricky every time the container will fall all the data of the containers that ran inside of Jenkins container will be lost and it will be docker inside docker.

Comment: You can mount a volume to prevent lost data. That shouldn't matter if you are running Docker in Docker or without